# How to check unique value according to id in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a table i.e. submenu

```
 Schema::create('submenu', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('submenu_id');
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1);
        $table->unsignedInteger('menu_id');
        $table->string('name');
       $table->tinyInteger('order');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('menu_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('menu')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

In this table, we input the value of order i.e. 1,2,3,4 in text box. 
Here, the order must start from 1 according to menu_id. Like, menu_id = 1 and order = 1 and order = 2, but the problem is the order must be unique. if there is already order = 1 in the menu_id = 1, then it must show the error message that "order already exists".

Now, the next menu_id = 2 also can have order = 1 and order = 2.
So, How to maintain unique value according to menu_id and check whether the menu_id contains the order or not?

SubmenuController

```
   $order = Input::get('order');
        $menu = Input::get('menu_id');
        if($menu->contains($order)){
            echo "exists";die;
        } else {
            echo "no exists";die;
        }
```

I have used this in controller, but it is not working...

Comment: So which column contains the order?

Comment: i have updated the info..

Answer (score 0):

Create a composite index of both columns:

```
Schema::create('submenu', function (Blueprint $table) {
    [...]
    $table->unique(['menu_id', 'order']);
});
```

In the controller, you can handle duplicate combinations like this:

```
try {
    Submenu::create($data);
} catch(Exception $exception) {
    // This combination of menu_id and order already exists.
}
```

Comment: I extended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a Select query in controller before doing some operation

```
   $order = Input::get('order');
    $menu = Input::get('menu_id');
    $var = DB::table('submenu')
     ->select('order','menu_id')
     ->where('order',$order)
     ->where('menu_id',$menu)
     ->first();

  if(!empty($var)){
        //Do Something for Duplicate Entry
    } else {
        //Do Something for Unique Entry;
    }
```

Comment: it is giving this error "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int"

Comment: Try Using This 
 `if(!empty($var)){}`
I have updated my answer

Comment: Please mark this answer as solved if it solved your issue